# Disabling Header Context Menu in Datagrid

Tags: c#, winforms, datagrid

How can I disable the header context menu on a datagrid in WinForms?

[image: Context Menu]

Comment: `dataGrid1.ContextMenu = New ContextMenu();`

Comment: Just to clarify, is this the old DataGrid in WinForms per your tag, or the DataGrid from WPF?

Comment: @LarsTech The old WinForms. Sorry for not clarifying it in my question.

Comment: @Jimi That worked beautifully, thanks. I feel silly for not noticing it.

Comment: You should probably have a private field (or whatever): `private ContextMenu emptyMenu = new ContextMenu();` then use it when needed: `dataGrid1.ContextMenu = emptyMenu;` and dispose of it on `Form.FormClosed()` (or whatever), so you don't allocate a new ContextMenu object every time you need an empty one .